# Freezing Cloth but keeping the momentum

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I want to animate and literally freeze a cloth object in the air. But I want it to keep its momentum.
Basically, it should act like cloth to a certain frame. After that, while keeping its simulated shape, I want it to keep its momentum. So it still needs to be a Rigid Body.

How can I do that?
Can I keyframe Cloth physics' sliders to act NOT like cloth after a certain frame?
Or is there a better way?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way would be to make a copy of the cloth at that frame, apply the cloth sim so it keeps the shape, make it a ridged body, then make the original cloth invisible at that frame and make the new one visible, seamless!

Comment: I thougth so. But then I guess I'd have to fake it's momentum. I was hoping there'd be a better way. That probably won't look natural.

Comment: You could parent the frozen cloth to the cloth sim, so when the cloth sim keeps moving (but is hidden) the frozen cloth keeps moving with it...??

Comment: That'll work! But I won't be able to have the object bump into other objects :D
Seems what I'm trying to do is a big deal. It really shouldn't be.